# IBM DB2 C Scalar UDF Error SQL0444N (reason code: 5)

Tags: c, db2, db2-luw

I am currently working on a project that involves developing a UDF for IBM DB2 v10 in C. All of my C code is bundled in a single file called `rcdudf.c` and it has the following contents:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sqlca.h>
#include <sqludf.h>

typedef unsigned int (*hash_function)(char*, unsigned int len);

unsigned int FNVHash (char* str, unsigned int len);

typedef struct hash_record 
{
    void* value;
    struct hash_record* next;
}hash_record;

typedef struct hash_bucket
{
    void* key;
    hash_record* head_record;
}hash_bucket;

typedef struct hash_table 
{
    int bucket_num;
    hash_bucket** hash_entry;
}hash_table;

int hash_init(hash_table** h_table, int bucket_num);

int hash_destroy(hash_table** h_table);

int hash_contains_key(hash_table** h_table, void* key, unsigned int key_len);

void hash_put_value(hash_table** h_table, void* key, unsigned int key_len, void* value, unsigned int value_len);

void hash_remove_value(hash_table** h_table, void* key, unsigned int key_len, void* value, unsigned int value_len);

void hash_print_contents(hash_table** h_table);

int hash_calculate_data_size(hash_table** h_table);

char* hash_concatenate_data_to_char_array(hash_table** h_table);


struct SCRATCHDATA 
{
    int num_buckets;
    hash_table *h_table;
};

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
void SQL_API_FN GatherDistinctValues( SQLUDF_VARCHAR *inputAttrKey, SQLUDF_VARCHAR *inputAttrValue, 
            SQLUDF_INTEGER *out, SQLUDF_SMALLINT *inputAttrKeyNullInd, SQLUDF_SMALLINT *inputAttrValueNullInd, 
        SQLUDF_SMALLINT *outInd, SQLUDF_TRAIL_ARGS_ALL)
{
    struct SCRATCHDATA *sp;
    sp = (struct SCRATCHDATA *) SQLUDF_SCRAT->data;
    switch (SQLUDF_CALLT)
    {
        case SQLUDF_FIRST_CALL:
            hash_init(&(sp->h_table), 7);
            break;
        case SQLUDF_NORMAL_CALL:
            if( *inputAttrKeyNullInd == 0 && *inputAttrValueNullInd  == 0 )
            {
                /**
                 * If the provided value is not NULL and it is not contained in the 
                 * Global hash Table, it is going to be added. Otherwise, 
                 * nothing is done (it already exists).
                 */
                if( hash_contains_key(&(sp->h_table), (void*) inputAttrKey, strlen(inputAttrKey)) == 0 )
                {
                    hash_put_value(&(sp->h_table), (void*) inputAttrKey, strlen(inputAttrKey), 
                            (void*) inputAttrValue, strlen(inputAttrValue));
                }
            }
            break;
        case SQLUDF_FINAL_CALL:
            break;
    }
    *out = 0;
    *outInd = 0;
    return;
}
```

In the rest of the file the bodies of the defined methods exist. In order to "install" this UDF to DB2, I execute the provided script `bldrtn` as follows:

```
~$./bldrtn rcdudf
```

and the executable is stored inside the `~/sqllib/function` directory. Next, I execute the following script in DB2:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GatherDistinctVal( VARCHAR(255), VARCHAR(255) )
    RETURNS INTEGER 
    EXTERNAL NAME 'rcdudf!GatherDistinctValues' 
    NOT FENCED 
    CALLED ON NULL INPUT 
    NOT VARIANT 
    NO SQL 
    PARAMETER STYLE SQL 
    LANGUAGE C 
    NO EXTERNAL ACTION;
```

By issuing the command `~$db2 -tvsf create-udf.sql`. After that I try to call the function on the Sample database of DB2 as follows:

```
~$ db2 "select gatherdistinctval('job',job) from employee"

1          
-----------
SQL0444N  Routine "*TINCTVAL" (specific name "SQL140520113052600") is 
implemented with code in library or path "...function/rcdudf", function 
"GatherDistinctValues" which cannot be accessed.  Reason code: "5".  
SQLSTATE=42724
```

When I define the aforementioned function as `FENCED` I receive the following error:

```
~$ db2 "select GatherDistinctVal('Job',job) from Employee"

1          
-----------
SQL1646N  A routine failed because the fenced user ID cannot access required 
files in the sqllib directory or other instance or database directories.
```

What am I doing wrong? I am pretty sure that the file `rcdudf` exists in the appropriate directory. Also, when I execute the `create-udf.sql` script, I get a success message from DB2.

When I execute `~$ls -l ~/sqllib/function/` I get the following:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root     db2iadm1    36 May 15 17:54 db2psmds -> /opt/ibm/db2/V10.1/function/db2psmds
drwxrwsr-t 2 db2inst1 db2iadm1  4096 May 15 17:54 db2rdf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root     db2iadm1    35 May 15 17:54 db2rtsc -> /opt/ibm/db2/V10.1/function/db2rtsc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root     db2iadm1    34 May 15 17:54 fpeevm -> /opt/ibm/db2/V10.1/function/fpeevm
-rw-r--r-- 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1  3256 May 20 17:58 GeneralHashFunctions.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1 11688 May 20 17:58 hash_table.o
-rwxr-xr-x 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1 17090 May 21 08:39 hopeless
drwxrwxr-x 3 db2inst1 db2iadm1  4096 May 14 16:07 jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root     db2iadm1    37 May 15 17:54 libdb2u.a -> /opt/ibm/db2/V10.1/function/libdb2u.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1 17144 May 20 18:08 rcdudf
drwxrwsr-t 2 db2inst1 db2iadm1  4096 May  8 21:24 routine
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root     db2iadm1    33 May 15 17:54 tblpd -> /opt/ibm/db2/V10.1/function/tblpd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1 22280 May 20 16:27 testudf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1 34510 May 20 09:49 udfcli
-rwxr-xr-x 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1 13009 May 20 10:42 udfsrv
drwxrwsr-t 2 db2inst1 db2iadm1  4096 May 15 17:54 unfenced
```

As can be seen, the rcdudf executable is there and it has read/execute permissions. Also, I am logged in as authorised user `db2inst1` when I perform all of the operations.

As an added experiment, I create the `ScalarUDF` function from the samples of DB2. The `sql` creation script of ScalarUDF is exactly the same as `create-udf.sql` with only the name changed. The executable file created in the `~/sqllib/function/` folder is `udfsrv`. 
When I try to execute `scalarudf` it works perfectly. I still do not understand why the fenced user is able to execute `scalarudf` but he is not able to execute `gatherdistinctvalues`.

I have posted the outcome of `db2 dbm get cfg` for future reference:

```
~$ db2 get dbm cfg

      Database Manager Configuration

Node type = Enterprise Server Edition with local and remote clients

Database manager configuration release level            = 0x0f00

CPU speed (millisec/instruction)             (CPUSPEED) = 2.637255e-07
Communications bandwidth (MB/sec)      (COMM_BANDWIDTH) = 1.000000e+02

Max number of concurrently active databases     (NUMDB) = 32
Federated Database System Support           (FEDERATED) = NO
Transaction processor monitor name        (TP_MON_NAME) = 

Default charge-back account           (DFT_ACCOUNT_STR) = 

Java Development Kit installation path       (JDK_PATH) = /opt/ibm/java-x86_64-71/

Database monitor heap size (4KB)          (MON_HEAP_SZ) = AUTOMATIC(90)
Java Virtual Machine heap size (4KB)     (JAVA_HEAP_SZ) = 2048
Audit buffer size (4KB)                  (AUDIT_BUF_SZ) = 0
Size of instance shared memory (4KB)  (INSTANCE_MEMORY) = AUTOMATIC(807642)
Instance memory for restart light (%) (RSTRT_LIGHT_MEM) = AUTOMATIC(10)
Agent stack size                       (AGENT_STACK_SZ) = 1024
Sort heap threshold (4KB)                  (SHEAPTHRES) = 0

Directory cache support                     (DIR_CACHE) = YES

Application support layer heap size (4KB)   (ASLHEAPSZ) = 15
Max requester I/O block size (bytes)         (RQRIOBLK) = 32767
Workload impact by throttled utilities(UTIL_IMPACT_LIM) = 10

Priority of agents                           (AGENTPRI) = SYSTEM
Agent pool size                        (NUM_POOLAGENTS) = AUTOMATIC(100)
Initial number of agents in pool       (NUM_INITAGENTS) = 0
Max number of coordinating agents     (MAX_COORDAGENTS) = AUTOMATIC(200)
Max number of client connections      (MAX_CONNECTIONS) = AUTOMATIC(MAX_COORDAGENTS)

Keep fenced process                        (KEEPFENCED) = YES
Number of pooled fenced processes         (FENCED_POOL) = AUTOMATIC(MAX_COORDAGENTS)
Initial number of fenced processes     (NUM_INITFENCED) = 0

Index re-creation time and redo index build  (INDEXREC) = RESTART

Transaction manager database name         (TM_DATABASE) = 1ST_CONN
Transaction resync interval (sec)     (RESYNC_INTERVAL) = 180
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the execution permissions? Can the instance and the fenced user execute your program?

Comment: Please provide the output of `ls -l ~/sqllib/function/*` showing your object file permissions.

Comment: First of all, thank you all for your interest. @AngocA : I execute everything as the user `db2inst1` which is in the DB2 administrators group. Therefore, I presume that this is not a problem. @mustaccio : I updated the initial post.

Comment: I am surr what i will say: try to put a main in your code, compile it, deploy it in the sqllib and then execute as db2inst1.

Comment: @AngocA actually the problem was neither permissions, nor a main. The problem was the default compilation script of DB2. I had to change it in order to bundle all of my different files into one. Thank you again for your interest though. Cheers!

Comment: Note that `FENCED` routines are executed in separate processes by the fenced user (usually `db2fenc1`, or whatever you defined when creating the instance) and not by the instance owner (`db2inst1` in your case), so the function object file need to be readable and executable by the fenced user.

Comment: @mustaccio thank you for the information. Can I ask you something else on this context also? Can the `db2fenc1` write on the local filesystem through a C UDF?

Comment: It hasn't anything to do with C UDFs or DB2 -- it depends on the filesystem permissions.

Comment: I see. Nevertheless, I have been debugging my UDFs and I find their behavior very unstable, in terms of file access and memory. For instance, I make my UDF to create a log file in `/tmp/` directory for outputting messages, and it is not always updated. Also, after many tests, even an empty UDF is not working in my DB2 instance. It is really frustrating to work in a DBMS with so little documentation and support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the `bldrtn` script of DB2 does not handle the case where code is used from more than one files. Also, it seems that adding code for defining the Hash Table and the Hash Functions in the beginning of my file did not work.

Create two different files `hash_table.h` and `hash_table.c` and type the code of my structures in there. Also, add the reference of `hash_table.h` in the `rcdudf.c` file. 
Afterwards change the `bldrtn` script to first create the object files of each source file, and then link them together.

In detail, the `bldrtn` file would have the following changed lines of code:

```
$CC $EXTRA_C_FLAGS  -I$DB2PATH/include -c hash_table.c -D_REENTRANT
$CC $EXTRA_C_FLAGS  -I$DB2PATH/include -c GeneralHashFunctions.c -D_REENTRANT
$CC $EXTRA_C_FLAGS  -I$DB2PATH/include -c rcdudf.c -D_REENTRANT

$CC $LINK_FLAGS -o rcdudf rcdudf.o GeneralHashFunctions.o hash_table.o $EXTRA_LFLAG -L$DB2PATH/$LIB -ldb2 -lpthread

rm -f $DB2PATH/function/hopeless
cp hopeless $DB2PATH/function
```

This way, my code is bundled in `rcdudf` and the DB2 can execute it completely.

*Note: It seems that every time a new UDF is registered, DB2 needs to be restarted*

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not an answer, but it's too big for a comment.

SQL0444N RC 5 can mean any of these things:

> ```
>      There is insufficient memory to load the library containing the
>      function or one or more symbols could not be resolved. This
>      reason code indicates one of the following situations:
> ```

```
     1. One or more symbols might not have been resolved. The
        routine library might be dependent on a shared library that
        cannot be located (using the concatenation of directories
        specified in the LIBPATH environment variable in UNIX-based
        systems, the PATH environment variable in INTEL systems).
     2. The routine has a 64-bit library which is not supported
        within a 32-bit DB2 instance, or, the routine has a 32-bit
        library or DLL within a 64-bit DB2 instance that is
        incompatible with the routine definition.
     3. There was insufficient memory to load the library containing
        the function.
```

Since you don't seem to use any extra libraries, I'd check the object file bitness vs. the instance bitness.

Comment: Thank you for your indication. I have come across this description before and I will tell you my thoughts for each point/number: 1) I do not have any dependent libraries, apart from `hash_table.h`, which I am currently examining whether it causes problems. 2) The OS is Ubuntu 12 x64 and the DB2 is also x64. Also, the script that builds the executable  makes sure my code is build for x64 system. 3) The memory setting for my DB2 is set to automatic. I will post the outcome of `dbm get cfg` in the initial post.

Comment: I have just experimented with the `#include "hash_table.h" and this seems to be causing all the problems. It seems that whenever I add this line to a UDF .c file, the function can not be called from the DB2 command line. Any ideas about how I can resolve this?